# return type for border in JFrame

Tags: java, return, border

I am creating a method, the below is just the skeleton

```
private Border createTitledBorder(Border border, String title)
{


}
```

Netbeans keeps prompting me for a return type.

The call to the method is:

```
Border paneEdge = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(5);

createTitledBorder(paneEdge, "Hello");
```

What is the return type? I thought it would have been Border?

Comment: Your question confuses me, and maybe it's me, but if you don't get a decent answer, please clarify. For one, post the exact message from your IDE, not a paraphrased version. For another, if your method is declared to return a Border, then in its body you **must return a Border object**. You don't show your code doing this.

Comment: I believe that is correct, but havent i got 2 return types? A string and a border?

Comment: You are greatly confused -- you're confusing method parameters with method return type. Run, don't walk to the nearest tutorial on methods to learn the difference.